# Determine if point is in 2 sigma error

Tags: python, optimization, uncertainty

I have a two dimensional space in x and y coordinates. I have a point (5,5) representing the mean and two sigma error is 2 for x coordinate and 3 for y coordinate. How do I determine if any (x,y) point is in the region defined by the two sigma bounds?

Comment: (Assuming multivariate normal, which I’m guessing you’re assuming...) This is something called Mahalanobis distance. You will evaluate if a point is two Mahalanobis distances away from the mean. The formula is on Wikipedia, and there are probably R and Python functions that will give you the Mahalanobis distance. You will need to know $cov(X,Y)$ (which you might be assuming to be zero).

Comment: Try drawing a graph with the point (5,5) on it.  If the two sigma error is 2 for the x co-ordinate, how small / how large can x be and still be within the bounds?  Draw vertical lines at those points.   Do the same for y (except horizontal lines).  You should get a box that shows you which points are within both of the two sigma bounds; that may help you develop some intuition about what is needed.